# How to change all the images in post content to full/orginal size - Thumbnails are broken

Tags: database, thumbnails

I use [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin and remove all my old thumbnails size.
Now, in my new theme I use new thumbnails for feature images, `But all inline images in my post content is broken`.

How can I change all the images in the post content to full/orginal size?

Comment: would re-adding your old thumbnail size fix this in the meantime? This looks like an X Y problem

Comment: @TomJNowell It is not just one size that can be recreated! There are several different sizes.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's a problem if regenerate thumbnails can recreate all of them, not just the `thumbnail` image size

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to WP CLI, make a [backup of your database](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/backing-up-your-database/) (I like using [WP-CLI `db export`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/export/)), and then use [the `search-replace` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) to change image URLs (untested):

```bash
wp search-replace "-150x150.jpg" ".jpg" --include-columns=post_content
```

Remember to change and run the command for every image size and file extension.

Comment: I can use this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/217645/200488 but unfortunately, the images are of different sizes and they do not all use the same size. for example -300x265.jpg, -300x541.jpg and ...

Comment: Ah yeah, that's true. 